# Django/Celery: Есть ли возможность создать непериодический task на заданное время?

Tags: django, celery

При сохранении объекта в базу, необходимо сразу же создать `celery task` на заданное время: например, сохраняем объект и через 3 часа статус объекта должен измениться. Есть ли такая возможность у `celery`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного матчасти: если вы task'и запускаете с помощью `delay`, примерно вот так:

```
your_task.delay(1, 2, foo=3, bar=4)
```

то вам следует знать, что это всего лишь обёртка над вызовом `apply_async`, которые вызывается примерно так:

```
your_task.apply_async((1, 2), {'foo': 3, 'bar': 4})
```

Первый аргумент — список позиционных аргументов для задачи (`args`), второй — словарь с именованными аргументами (`kwargs`).

Так вот, [apply_async](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.apply_async) помимо этого содержит ещё аргументы, некоторые из которых как раз подходят для вашего случая:

- `countdown`: через сколько секунд запустить задачу
- `eta`: в какое время (объект datetime) запустить задачу (обратите внимание, что время здесь должно быть в UTC!)

Соответственно, запустить задачу через 3 часа можно так:

```
your_task.apply_async(args, kwargs, countdown=3600 * 3)  # в 1 часе 3600 секунд
```

Или вот так:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
your_task.apply_async(args, kwargs, eta=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=3))
```

Учтите, что ни тот, ни другой способ не гарантируют, что task выполнится в строго заданное время: по куче всяких самых разных причин возможны погрешности плюс-минус несколько секунд.